# How to bind grouped ListView where GroupItemCount is dependent on data

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, grouping

I've got a situation where I'm populating a ListView on a product page with product part records retrieved from our content management system. A page may contain 1-n parts. Product parts can be discontinued and, if they are discontinued, there is the option to link to a new/replacement product page. The discontinuation flag and the link to the new/replacement page are all done at the part level in our CMS.

The request I've received is to group all the discontinued part records together under one common "discontinuation" header if they are all linking to the same new/replacement product page (we often have multiple part numbers/SKUs for different sizes of the same product).

So, something like the following:

```
Raw data:
Part 1  -  Discontinued  -  Links to Page X
Part 2  -  Discontinued  -  Links to Page X
Part 3  -  Not Discontinued
Part 4  -  Discontinued  -  Links to Page Y
Part 5  -  Discontinued  -  Links to Page Y
Part 6  -  Discontinued  -  Links to Page Y
Part 7  -  Not Discontinued
```

Requested output (the preceding @ would indicate different visual styling between discontinued and non-discontinued rows):

```
------------------------------------------------------
| @ Product has been discontinued. Please see Page X |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| @ Part 1                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| @ Part 2                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| Part 3                                             |
|----------------------------------------------------|   
| @ Product has been discontinued. Please see Page Y |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| @ Part 4                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| @ Part 5                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| @ Part 6                                           |
|----------------------------------------------------|
| Part 7                                             |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I can see how I could iterate through all the parts assigned to the page and sort/group them by their target new/replacement page, put them into a Dictionary that I can loop through later, whatever, but I'm not finding much about whether it'd be possible to bind them in the ListView this way. They are, logically, "groups," so using the ListView grouping would be great, but can you do that with dynamic GroupItemCounts?

Due to time constraints, refactoring the code to not use a ListView is not an option at this point. It is more an option to not do this grouping, but I'd like to accommodate the request if I can.

Any help/hints would be appreciated, or, if it's not doable, confirmation of that is appreciated, too. Thanks in advance!